# Upgrading to Django 1.7. AssertionError: To use StatusField, the model 'ShellRequest' must have a STATUS choices class attribute

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I was upgrading from Django 1.6 to 1.7. Python 2.7 is installed which is compatible with Django 1.7. While I did run the code `python manage.py makemigrations`, I got the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/m                           akemigrations.py", line 111, in handle
    convert_apps=app_labels or None,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/autodetector.py", line 42, in changes
    changes = self._detect_changes(convert_apps, graph)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/autodetector.py", line 109, in _detect_changes
    self.old_apps = self.from_state.render(ignore_swappable=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 67, in render
    model.render(self.apps)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 312, in render
    body,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 284, in __new__
    new_class._prepare()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 344, in _prepare
    signals.class_prepared.send(sender=cls)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 198, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/model_utils/fields.py", line 57, in prepare_class
    % sender.__name__
AssertionError: To use StatusField, the model 'ShellRequest' must have a STATUS choices class attribute.
```

Reading the blogpost [here](http://github.com/jazzband/django-model-utils/issues/29), I couldn't figure out where to start. If anyone can give me a guideline how to deal with this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: I will be happy to answer any relevant question.

Comment: Maybe add the `model` you are making the migrations off of.

Answer (score 1):

The [`choices`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#choices) class field attribute is probably what you're looking for.

If you are using `django-model-utils`, the [`choices`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-model-utils/1.1.0#choices) section of the package doc might help too.